# Zoom Web SDK (Component View) not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, zoom-sdk

I am trying to integrate the Zoom Embedded Client using Zoom Web SDK and the Component View. From a technical point of view, this also works without any problems. I can join any meeting and participate in it. I also have some experience with the client view in an iFrame. However, I can't manage to style the component view responsively. I simply want the zoom container to follow the outer coin container (width: 100%, height: 100%), so that the zoom container always adapts itself. Unfortunately this is not possible. According to the API you can assign values in pixels, but only once during initialization. If I use CSS to define the root container of the Zoom Client to position: relative and width: 100% it works with this container, but the content of the Zoom Client (the videos of the meeting) do not follow this and stay fixed on their width and height.
Does anyone have an idea how to embed the zoom container responsively?

Comment: I reached out to Zoom Support about this same issue recently, and they mentioned that the Zoom Web SDK Component View as of 2.7.0 is not responsive and only takes pixel values at time of init. Hopefully they fix/improve this in an upcoming release. You could probably make it responsive with enough css muscling, but there are a lot of layers of elements in the zoom widget which makes it difficult.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I hope so too. I had already put hours into CSS optimizations at that time, unfortunately without significant success. The result was: Responsiveness in the init process (always adapts to the current context), but after that no more.
I'm curious whether Zoom improves again...